# How to lock height of two divs together?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create two `div`s with same height. The height of each `div` is different on every page (height depends on content). Is there any way how to lock the height of two `div`s together? Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zPD2/) (I need to increse the height of `div` C based on `div` A and conversely).

Note: I cant use table or parent `div`. I am a newbie in JavaScript, so I hope that it can be done without it.

```
<div class="a">
    <brdsds><br><br><br><bdsdsr><br><br><br>ds<br>dsds<br>dsd
</div>
<div class="b">
    dsdds
</div>
<div class="c">
    dsdds
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `display:table-cell`, first remove the `float` and add this:

```
div {
 width 30px;
 display:table-cell;/*Add this*/
 /*float:left; Remove this*/
}
```

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/8zPD2/1/

*Before use this check the **[Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/css-table)***

Comment: please note that `display:table-cell` is supported `IE8` and above, mentioning because question isn't tagged `css3` :)

Comment: @NoobEditor yep adding compatibility :)

Comment: Great but is possible to make somethink similar with this http://jsfiddle.net/8zPD2/2/ ?

Comment: And is possible to do it with only div A and C (I need to have div B  with constant height over div C) http://jsfiddle.net/8zPD2/2/

Comment: @user3016214 you should need another properties and maybe structure to do that with just CSS and your actual markup. check this http://jsfiddle.net/8zPD2/7/

Comment: @user3016214 np mate glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

**Just need to use this CSS:**

```css
.a,
.c {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div class="divmaster">
  <div class="divchild">
    <brdsds><br><br><br><bdsdsr><br><br><br>ds<br>dsds<br>dsd
 </div>
 <div class="divchild">
    dsdds
 </div>
 <div class="divchild">
    dsdds
 </div>
```

and the css:

```
.divmaster{
    display:table;
 }

.divChild{
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: As i said. I can't use parent div :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try this in JavaScript , Use this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/ZtLpe/)**

```
$(function(){ 
setHeight = function (src, target) { 
h = src.height(); 
target.css('height', h + 'px'); 
} 
content = $('.a'); 
imagediv = $('.b'); 
setHeight(content, imagediv); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your div to `display: table-cell`, and then remove the `float: left`.

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    width 30px;
}

.a {
    background-color: #e9d8b7;
}

.b {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/8zPD2/6/

Answer (score 0):

Set min height to height of the div which has high height. Say if your div A has highest height the use that height to all divs. Its not possible with css if you dont know which div might have heigest div. As you asked how to do it only with css here it is

```
.a,.b,.c{ min-height:200px; max-height:400px; }
```